# Powershell Script Will Not Run Unless I Copy Contents To A New File

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a powershell script designed to run every hour as a scheduled task to do a connectivity test to a number of servers and websites to ensure that the specific network links are active (they are prone to issues and we don't have access to monitoring software for this short-term need). 
I set it up as a workflow that takes a list of servers and does a foreach -Parallel Test-NetConnection. I used the workflow and -Parallel option to keep runtime down. The results are added to a table which is output and stored as a variable outside of the workflow, then emailed to me.

This all worked fine initially. I set up the scheduled task and did some tests with good and bad server names to ensure it behaved correctly. Today I come in and there was a link disruption but no email. The history showed the tasks completed every hour. I tried opening the script in the ISE and got the following error when I tried to run it:

An error occurred while calling tracking participants causing the instance to be aborted.  See the inner exception for more details.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [], OperationCanceledException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStateFailed

I did try to add a catch $_.exception.innerException.message but was unable to get any result from the script (it still just gave the error above).

*HOWEVER*; if I copy/paste the entire contents of the script to a new file it works just as expected. I even copied the bad .ps1 file to my workstation and was able to duplicate the same behavior (fails with tracking participants error, but copy/paste the code into a new file and it works), so it doesn't look like a computer specific issue. Also, if I save the "bad" file as a new file name it remains "bad". Permissions on "bad" and "good" files are identical.

So while I have a workaround by recreating the file with a copy/paste of the script, since I don't know why it broke in the first place, I don't know if it will do it again. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this kind of behavior?

Sanitized code below:

```bsh
Workflow Test-Connection 
{
$AnyFailures = "No" #Initially set failure toggle to "No" so no email alert is sent unless the toggle is switched by a failure in one or more of the tests.
$MyTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
<#
Edit ComputerName variable list to add or remove computers to be monitored for RDP, SFTP, and SCP access (Ports 3389, 22).
Entries should be double quoted and comma separated. Either IP address or FQDN can be used.
Example: $ComputerName = "192.168.0.1", "testcomputer.domain"
#>
    $ComputerName = "1.2.3.4", "2.3.4.5", "3.4.5.6", "4.5.6.7", "5.6.7.8"
<#
Edit WebsiteName variable list to add or remove websites to be monitored for HTTPS access (Port 443).
Entries should be double quoted and comma separated. Do not include the protocol identifier from the URL "HTTPS://".
Example: $WebsiteName = "www.google.com", "yahoo.com"
#>
    $WebsiteName = "website.com", "website2.com", "website3.com", "website4.com"

    #Test Computers for RDP (port 3389) connectivity.
    foreach -Parallel ($Computer in $ComputerName)
    {
        sequence 
        {
        $Port = 3389
        $Test = (Test-NetConnection -Port $Port -ComputerName $Computer )
        If ($Test.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $True) 
            {
            $Status = "Success on RDP on port $Port"
            }
        Else 
            {
            $Status = "Failure on RDP on port $Port"
            $WORKFLOW:AnyFailures = "Yes" # Trigger Email if there are any failures.
            }
        #Write Status output to an object to be used to create a table at the end of the script.
        $Obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $Computer
            Status = $Status
            }
        $Obj
        }
    }

    #Test Computers for SFTP/SCP (port 22) connectivity.
     foreach -Parallel ($Computer in $ComputerName) 
    {
        sequence 
        {
        $Port = 22
        $Test = (Test-NetConnection -Port $Port -ComputerName $Computer )
        If ($Test.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $True) 
            {
            $Status = "Success on FTPS/SCP on port $Port"
            }
        Else 
            {
            $Status = "Failure on FTPS/SCP on port $Port"
            $WORKFLOW:AnyFailures = "Yes" # Trigger Email if there are any failures.
            }
        #Write Status output to an object to be used to create a table at the end of the script.
        $Obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $Computer
            Status = $Status
            }
        $Obj
        }
    }

    #Test Websites for HTTPS (port 443) connectivity.
    foreach -Parallel ($Website in $WebsiteName) 
    {
        sequence 
        {
        $Port = 443
        $Test = (Test-NetConnection -Port $Port -ComputerName $Website )
        If ($Test.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $True) 
            {
            $Status = "Success on HTTPS on port $Port"
            }
        Else 
            {
            $Status = "Failure on HTTPS on port $Port"
            $WORKFLOW:AnyFailures = "Yes" # Trigger Email if there are any failures.
            }
        #Write Status output to an object to be used to create a table at the end of the script.
        $Obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $Website
            Status = $Status
            }
        $Obj
        }
    }
}
$MyTable = Test-Connection | Select -Property Server, Status | Format-Table -AutoSize
$EmailTable = $MyTable | Out-String


    IF ($MyTable | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "Failure on")
    {
$MyTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
$smtpserver = "emailserver.example"
$from = "emailaddress@example.com"
$to = "to-email@example.com"
$subject = "Connection Test Has Failed"
$body = “One or more automated connection tests failed at $MyTime. `n `n Please review the table below for details. `n $EmailTable `n `n `n `n This email was generated from a scheduled task titled 'My-sheduled-task' running on SERVER.Example on an hourly schedule."
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -body $body -port 25
 }
```

Comment: Post code we can test.  This could be one time glitch that corrupted the file.

Comment: Thanks! I have added a sanitized version of the script to my post.

Comment: If you remake the script then the hash of the file will change. I starting to think that your antivirus thinks your program is a evil port scanner.  Given the speed that you checking ports and pinging it makes sense.  Make an exception in the antivirus for the file.

Comment: I think you could be right. Thanks for the suggestion!